# How to remove an offline emulator from avd devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I've created a couple of AVD-s in Android Studio.  They were launching on emulator port 5554.  Then I've created another AVD via `android avd` application, and they are starting on port 5556.

Now with a single emulator running, I get the following output from `adb devices -l`:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5556          device
emulator-5554          offline
```

I'm using the tooling which cannot supply the `-s` (specific device) option to `adb`, so when trying to install an app, I get an error:

```
error: more than one device/emulator
```

And I'd like that there be a single connected emulator: the only one that I'm running.

I thought that removing the old Android Studio-created devices would do the trick of removing the emulator-5554, but nope.  Even new devices created in Studio will open on 5556.  So I've ended up with a forever-offline zombie `emulator-5554` that screws up my build tooling.

How can I force the new emulators to be run on port 5554 and/or remove the offline `emulator-5554`?

(Running Ubuntu 16.04 if it matters.)

Comment: I didn't realize that my phone was connected through USB ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When I am facing the same issues than doing like below:

1. Restart adb by issuing `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` in a command prompt
2. Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
3. Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.

99% of my issues have been resolved with these steps.

Comment: Thanks, the `kill-server` and `start-server` combo worked!

Comment: I don't know whether this is a solution, but after trying all the three methods suggested by @Chandrama Prasad

    1) Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a cmd prompt
    2) Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
    3) Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.
when all the three did not work, I simply changed my USB cable, and nos duplicate device shown after that. Please note that I was not using emulator but personal Android device.
Simply put there was a trouble in my data cable.

Answer (score 20):

I have this problem on MacOS and solved it by

1. Open the Spotlight search: Press `Command + Spacebar`
2. Type `Activity Monitor`
3. Open the Activity Monitor
4. Search for `qemu`
5. Force quit the qemu process

Restarting adb like an answer above did not help.

Comment: For windows the same can be done by
1. Open Task Manager
2. Search for qemu
3. Right click the process and select End Task

Comment: Best answer for macOS users.  Nothing else worked for me

Answer (score 4):

This is an often thing that happens, follow this steps:

1. Windows+R
2. type services.msc
3. stop BlueStacks Android Service

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm running Ubuntu.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Normally killing the ADB process do the trick also. You could also try to uncheck  "Launch From Snapshot"

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, the only way I've been able to solve this has been by restarting my computer (sometimes twice).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find BlueStack on services but I manage to get it solved by 'end task' on Task Manager under Processes.

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED **
https://github.com/freeload101/SCRIPTS/blob/5295f2b96581917c09ade309f91a7c46be370b7e/Windows_Batch/Android_Debloat_N_Dump.bat#L53

```
echo [+] %date% %time% INFO: Trying to find and kill processes on port 5563 that will break adb  
FOR /F "tokens=5 " %%A in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr :5563') do (
echo [+] %date% %time% INFO: Killing process PID "%%A"
taskkill /PID %%A /F
)


echo [+] %date% %time% INFO: Killing any existing adb server
"%~dp0platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server

:: kill all nox app player adb and adb ..
taskkill /F /IM adb.exe 2> %~dp0\null
taskkill /F /IM nox_adb.exe 2> %~dp0\null
```

I can't seem to find emulator-5562 any place ... searching my entire disk ... if I start adb no matter what I get emulator-5562 after a few seconds ... no other adb running or emulators etc no bluestacks BS or android studio .. FYI my Android Testing Suite JAMBOREE gets you up an running in under 2min

https://github.com/freeload101/Java-Android-Magisk-Burp-Objection-Root-Emulator-Easy/

taskkill /F /IM adb.exe

adb kill-server normally works but ... in my case ...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, find the process with:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<emulator port>
```

then kill the process with:

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this may help someone else, here's how I resolved this when using **WiFi ADB** and **Termux** to connect and run adb commands on my phone, from my phone (no PC required, but I think the phone may need to be rooted):

first, in **Settings > System > Developer Options > Running Services**, click the menu at the top right, and select **Show cached processes**. Then, scroll through the list to find BlueStack, click on it, and then click the **stop** button.

After that, open Termux and do the following:

```
~ $ adb kill-server
~ $ adb kill-server
cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused
~ $ adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline

~ $
```

now, open the WiFi ADB app and switch it off. Then, to check and ensure the adb session and offline emulator are gone, do the following in Termux:

```
~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached

~ $ adb kill-server
~ $ adb kill-server
cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused
~ $ adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached

~ $
```

at this point, go back and switch WiFi ADB back on again. Then, in Termux again:

```
~ $ adb connect localhost
connected to localhost:5555
~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached
localhost:5555  device

~ $
```

Done! No more phantom/zombie emulator!

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when running on windows. I solved it by just restarting Android studio.